# ViewModels (and maybe Views) still active after switching Views with RequestNavigate in WPF/Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ninject, prism

Most of my view models subscribe to a common event using Prism's EventAggregator on a WPF project. Basically, a vocal command triggers this event on a view, and as a response the view will publish another event containing its specific message to a text-to-speech module. 
However, when I implemented this, I realized that when using RegionManager's RequestNavigate to switch to another view, the previous view model is still somehow active. When I trigger the common event for the most recent view, it is also triggered for the previous view.

Simplified example :

1. Start at View 1
2. Trigger common event
3. Response : message from View 1
4. RequestNavigate to View 2
5. Trigger common event
6. Response : message from View 2, then message from View 1
7. RequestNavigate to View 3
8. Trigger common event
9. Response : message from View 3, then View 2, then View 1
10. etc.

I placed a breakpoint on View 1, View 2 and View 3's common event, and each time I get a message from a view, its breakpoint is hit.

What I would like is simple : I don't want the previous ViewModel (and possibly View too) to be still somehow active when I'm switching Views. Even better would be for them to be garbage collected, because I also had some weird cases where by navigating to View 1, View 2 and View 1 again, the message for View 1 was sent twice (and its breakpoint also hit twice), so I'm not even sure if multiple references for the ViewModels are created, which could potentially lead to a memory leak.

I tried to reproduce this behavior by creating another project with just the essentials, so here's the code. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with .net framework 4.5.2 and Ninject.

Shell.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PrismTest.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:prsm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Name="MainRegion" prsm:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

NinjectPrismBootstrapper.cs

```
public class NinjectPrismBootstrapper : NinjectBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void InitializeModules()
        {
            base.InitializeModules();

            // Text to speech
            Kernel.Bind<SpeechSynthesizer>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
            Kernel.Bind<INarrator>().To<StandardNarrator>().InSingletonScope();
            Kernel.Bind<INarratorEventManager>().To<NarratorEventManager>().InSingletonScope();

            // View models
            Kernel.Bind<MainPageViewModel>().ToSelf();
            Kernel.Bind<SecondPageViewModel>().ToSelf();

            // Views
            Kernel.Bind<object>().To<MainPageView>().InTransientScope().Named(typeof(MainPageView).Name);
            Kernel.Bind<object>().To<SecondPageView>().InTransientScope().Named(typeof(SecondPageView).Name);

            Kernel.Bind<Shell>().ToSelf();

            var narratorEventManager = Kernel.Get<INarratorEventManager>();

            var regionManager = Kernel.Get<IRegionManager>();
            regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MainPageView));
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return (Shell)Kernel.GetService(typeof(Shell));
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();
            Application.Current.MainWindow = (Shell)this.Shell;
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

MainPageView.xaml (my starting page)

```
<UserControl x:Class="PrismTest.Views.MainPageView"
             namespaces...>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Main page"/>
        <Button Content="Narrator speaks" Command="{Binding Path=NarratorSpeaksCommand}" />
        <Button Content="Next page" Command="{Binding Path=GoToNextPageCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

MainPageView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPageView : UserControl
    {
        public MainPageView(MainPageViewModel dataContext)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = dataContext;
        }
    }
```

MainPageViewModel (View model for MainPageView)

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, IRegionMemberLifetime, INavigationAware
    {
        private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
        private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

        public DelegateCommand GoToNextPageCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand NarratorSpeaksCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainPageViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator, IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            _regionManager = regionManager;

            ConfigureCommands();

            //The original common event triggered by a vocal command is simulated in this project by simply clicking on a button
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CommonEventToAllViews>().Subscribe(NarratorSpeaks);
        }

        private void ConfigureCommands()
        {
            GoToNextPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoToNextPage);
            NarratorSpeaksCommand = new DelegateCommand(ClickPressed);
        }

        private void GoToNextPage()
        {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate("MainRegion", new Uri("SecondPageView", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void ClickPressed()
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CommonEventToAllViews>().Publish();
        }

        private void NarratorSpeaks()
        {
            _eventAggregator.GetEvent<NarratorSpeaksEvent>().Publish("Main page");
        }
    }
```

I don't need to put the code for SecondPageViewModel and SecondPageView, because it's the exact same code except RequestNavigate sends the user back to MainPageView and its NarratorSpeaks method sends a different string.

What I tried :

1) Making MainPageViewModel and SecondPageViewModel inherit IRegionMemberLifetime and setting KeepAlive to false

2) Inheriting INavigationAware and returning false in IsNavigationTarget method

3) Adding this to OnNavigatedFrom method from INavigationAware :

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
            var region = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"];
            var view = region.Views.Single(v => v.GetType().Name == "MainPageView");
            region.Deactivate(view);
        }
```

Worth noting : even without the deactivate part, if I put a breakpoint after var region = _regionManager.Regions["MainRegion"]; and check region.views, there is only one result, no matter how much I switch views.

Nothing worked, events keep being triggered in previous views as I switch views back and forth.
So, I'm kind at a loss here. I'm not sure if it's my way of registering Views and ViewModels in Ninject that triggers this, or something else, but if someone has a suggestion, I'll gladly take it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems in the past. Have you considered unsubscribe from events when navigated from?

Comment: Yes, actually in my original project, I use Unsubscribe as a temporary measure to prevent the speech synthesizer to pile on messages and just say the current one. However, what worries me is that when I do something like, go to view 1 > view 2 > view 1 again, the message from view 1 is repeated, making me think that maybe multiple references of ViewModels are being created and not processed by garbage collector, eventually leading to a memory leak. I tried waiting 5mn after doing this view switching, and I still had the same messages being processed.

Comment: I don't really know how much time it takes to garbage collector to process unused references, and since I'm a beginner with WPF and Prism, I wanted to make sure that I wasn't doing something wrong. Is it actually the normal behavior of unused ViewModels?

Comment: @Bob_ZombX: The GC is not deterministic, it can run on system idle or memory pressure. As long as you don´t hold references to the View it should be collected. Consider that INavigationAware allows to reuse your View instances.

Comment: Ok, so basically, I just have to use Unsubscribe to only get the message of the current view, and I shouldn't worry about the unused ViewModels, because at some point, even if it seems a bit long, they'll be collected?

Comment: @Bob_ZombX: You can try if they survive a full collection:  GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();

Comment: After adding these lines on my test project, it removed the messages from previous ViewModels. On my main project however, the problem persists, So this means something is holding a reference of my ViewModels. At the very least, I now know it's not something specific to Prism. Thank you very much for your help!